# How to disregards the object while querying using ActiveRecord::Base methods whose associated object has been deleted from database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, rails-activerecord

I have `Person<ActiveRecord::Base` model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :sender
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :receiver 

 #.....

end
```

and another modeActiveRecord::Base model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Person'

  # ......
end
```

; and ActiveRecord::Migration class supporting these models. Now my problem is that I need to output the `messages` received by current user with the `Person name` of sender by querying database, but while querying it seems that some of the person(user) who sent the messages has been deleted from database(but messages once exchanged b/w two persons is saved permanently in database and no body have the permission to delete it, So each message will be there with all the details like `receiver_id` and `sender_id` .). So when I query like this.

```
@messages = Message.where(:receiver_id => current_user.id)
                   .includes(:sender).order("updated_at DESC")------------(1)
```

it works fine if person who has sent the message to currently logged in user has it's `delete_at` attribute null(meaning not deleted from database and can be used without any error in views for `sender name`) but for those which has been deleted it gives this error in browser console

```
in application controller asset is undefined method or variable  ----------(2)
```

where a method in application controller to handle no record found exception

```
def respond_to_not_found(*types)
      flash[:warning] = t(:msg_asset_not_available, asset)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(redirection_url) }
        # ...
      end
end
```

please tell What is the `t` and `asset` is in answer ???

So as a workaround of problem `(1)`  -------- (3).
I queried this and

```
def show_list
  @messages = Array.new
  @person = Array.new
  messages_temp = Message.where(:receiver_id => current_user.id).
                        includes(:sender).order("updated_at DESC")

  i = 0
  messages_temp.each do |msg|
    if(!(msg.sender.nil?))
      @messages[i] = msg
      @person[i] = msg.sender
      i = i+1
    end
  end
end
```

My **questions**:-

Q.1) I haven't much worked with database so this is valid question for me(as the project I am working on explicitly destroys the requested user):- Why the user info has not been deleted from database but rather it's `deleted_at` attribute has become `not null` whereas for others which are intact have same attribute `null`. And when I `find`(query by method `find`) an object of `Person` from database then while querying it's SQL conversion query for `deleted_at` attribute should be `null`. So why is happening am I missing something in my project code or it is general behaviour. If it general then how to completely expunge the data. 
Even if such behaviour is general or not how to recover it, without manually changing each deleted Person `deleted_at` attribute to null. And how to access some of it's attribute without fully restoring the Person(or if such thing is possible).

Q.2) What might be other reasons for getting error #(2) even after workaround. As I tested the workaround and it worked fine for some of deleted sender's. But even after  at some places I am getting error #(2) so in general what does this error stand for and what might be it's other cause then the one I mentioned???

Q.3)Is there better solution then the workaround given in eq #(3) because you see in my workaround `msg.sender.nil?` is true for the deleted object so I think there might be some. I tried the net but with no success. So, how to filter out those messages whose associated object is deleted how to query them all at once then doing it one by one as in #(2). 
As workaround is giving me hard time to paginate the output because all the available `pagination gem` (for example '`will_paginate`', '`kaminari`', '`pagination`') works on `ActiveRelation` but in my workaround I have Array object i.e `@messages`on which I can not use these methods. So it would be great help if one can answer a way to paginate my workaround  i.e object `@messages` which is an array or a way to filter out those messages whose sender is deleted from database then I can paginate in this way :-

```
@messages = Message.<ActiveRecord::Base method to get the desired output>.paginate[params]
```

PS:-  I know the question is tedious but I believe it is essential for this question I am seeking answer to. Any help will be appreciated even the partial answer to the question.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...

Well it took me couple of days but with some help from my vicinity I did figure out answer to most of the confusion and ambiguity:

Ans:- 
1:) There is a way to soft delete the data meaning hidden from normal query... Most of ambiguities of question one can be answered from this `[link][1]`. This `gem`(**acts_as_paranoid**) helps soft deleting the data. yes, attributes of soft deleted object can be accessed without restoring the date; and data can be completely expunged as well(everything in the link). The changes I needed to make in my code base to avail these benefits are these:-

In `Person<ActiveRecord::Base` model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 # has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :sender
 # has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :receiver 
 has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', 
           :inverse_of => [:sender, :sender_including_deleted]
 has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', 
           :inverse_of => [:receiver, :receiver_including_deleted]


 #.....

end
```

and in the model `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'Person'

  # Add these two lines:-
  belongs_to :sender_including_deleted, :class_name => 'Person', 
             :foreign_key => 'sender_id', :with_deleted => true
  belongs_to :receiver_including_deleted, :class_name => 'Person', 
             :foreign_key => 'receiver_id', :with_deleted => true 


  # ......
end
```

So, adding these two lines worked for me but most importantly the gem helped me a lot.

2:) One of prominent reason for getting error in (2) is that one may be trying to directly access the attribute of object which may be deleted. Suppose a `Person` is deleted(soft or hard doesn't matter whose id was 15) so `first_name = Person.find(15).first_name` will give error where as `person = Person.find(15)` `if(!person.nil?) return first_name` will not as we are checking if returned `person` is nil or not. and if Person is deleted with gem `acts_as_paranoid` then a `soft deleted`(meaning `deleted_at` attribute is `not null`. The deleted_at(this attribute has to be added in migration to use) attribute is updated when object is deleted for clear picture see the embedded link [here](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid)) object accessed  `first_name = Person.with_delete.find(15)` like this won't generate an error

`Note:-`  I don't what might be other reason. please answer this part if you can think of any.

3:)  Although I do not have direct answer to question asked in 3 but since now I can access the message sender info even though they are deleted(in active relation form) so ordering and pagination works but I surely like to know how to paginate if object in not active relation.

So, this one I best answered like this:-

```
def show_list

  # @messages = Array.new
  # @person = Array.new
  # messages_temp = Message.where(:receiver_id => current_user.id).
  #                       includes(:sender).order("updated_at DESC")

  # i = 0
  # messages_temp.each do |msg|
  #   if(!(msg.sender.nil?))
  #     @messages[i] = msg
  #     @person[i] = msg.sender
  #     i = i+1
  #   end
  # end

  # REPLACE ABOVE CODE BY THIS. THe following code will 
  # include deleted messages as well. 
  @person = Array.new
  @messages = Message.where(:receiver_id =>current_user.id).
                      includes(:sender_including_deleted).
                      order("created_at DESC").paginate(params).readonly

  i = 0
  @messages.each do |msg|       
    @person[i] = msg.sender_including_deleted(:with_deleted => true)
    i = i + 1
  end


end
```

I hope the people who stumbled upon this question get what they are looking. If they  didn't get any part of my answer or question then they are welcome to comment here and I will be happy to answer to best of my abilities.